# I got -1 after I commented on an answer

Tags: discussion, comments, downvotes

I was looking for an answer (to my problem on how to add padding in options in a select field) on Stack Overflow earlier today. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28577941/add-padding-to-the-select-options-and-change-the-border-color/28577985#28577985) and searched for the answer within. Unfortunately, it isn't possible to add padding in options in select field. But I scrolled a little to see another answer (which wasn't working) and then I commented on it saying that "it isn't working."

A couple of minutes ago I saw a downvote and my Stack Overflow reputation went down by 1 for commenting on a post, I guess.

Am I missing something here?

[image: Reputation change]

Comment: You *downvoted an answer*. Commenting does not cause your rep to change.

Comment: You also downvoted that answer, which is what costs 1 reputation when doing it to an answer.

Comment: Note that normally votes are anonymous. By posting that screenshot you've revealed that you voted on an answer on that question.

Comment: So if I downvote an answer the karma will be deducted from mine?

Comment: Yes, downvoting on answers costs you 1 reputation point. See the duplicate.

Comment: Yes I voted down on it because the answer wasn't helping anybody nor was it correct.

Comment: Which is exactly why you *should* be downvoting. You didn't do anything wrong here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, cody and others  Thanks guys. Looks like I didn't know some of the rules.

Comment: @Rahul: excellent, that's what voting is for! Thank you for helping to improve the site.

Comment: Nothing to be ashamed at for downvoting. It's useful to control quality on the site. If you find something to be bad, downvote away.

Comment: The reason that answer downvotes cost a point, is that people abused downvoting. People would downvote competing answers to make their own answers look better (tactical downvoting). It would be better if downvotes on answers could be free, but... well, that's been abused too often in the past. You did the right thing, and you'll recover that lost point soon enough.

Comment: @S.L.Barth No, the reason that downvoting costs a point is that the site owners *feared* that people would do that.  It was in fact put in place before the site ever even launched.  It was not done in response to abuse.  It was done preemptively out of fear of *potential* abuse.  While abuse using downvotes does happen on rare occasion (even with the 1 rep cost) we don't actually know how much that cost actually prevents, because the site has never been without it.